# How to find the Hawking temperature for this metric?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, hawking-radiation, kerr-newman-metric

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.3680v1.pdf) about "Hawking radiation of Kerr-Newman-de Sitter black hole", where the authors find Hawking temperature of this metric

### [image]

The authors state that hawking temperature is given by

[image]

The problem is I am not sure how [image] gives [image]. I have differentiated $\Delta_{r}$ with respect $r$ and did not get the same result. How did the author get the term on the RHS of equation $(8)$?

Thanks.

Comment: I took a quick look at the paper. It seems that they are using equations 6-7 to manipulate the expression. In particular it seems that $M$ is replaced with the help of equation $7$. But maybe you are already aware of this.

Comment: @DelCrosB, I did notice that but I am still not sure how they got their result.

Comment: Is your question how the expression for $T_+$ is obtained in the first place (which would be a question about the physics of Hawking radiation) or solely how the r.h.s. of eq. (8) is obtained, which seems to just be a question about algebraic manipulations.